# cannot read property 'emit' of undefined socketio

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc, serversocket

I'm building a project using socket.io.
while running getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined".

server code is given below:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`)
})

app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
  res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room })
})

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
    socket.join(roomId)
    socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId)

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', userId)
    })
  })
})

server.listen(3000)
```

Can anyone help to rectify the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your socket function is written in the wrong order

Try this:

```
socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('user-connected', userId)
```

and this:

```
  socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('user-disconnected', userId)
```

Comment: I think the new socketio version is the issue. This worked for me. Thanks @kuntervert

Answer (score 0):

- If you're getting this error, I'm assuming you are following this
  video tutorial [How To Create A Video Chat App With WebRTC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvlyzDZDEq4&t=853s)
- In this tutorial Kyle is using `socket.io` version `2.0.3`
- You are facing issues since you might be using socket version `'4.0.1'`.
  Apparently in this version, the `broadcast` property is no longer
  available/has been removed which is why you are getting the above TypeError.
- Also call the `'to()'` method on the `io` object instead of the `socket` object.

*Solution:*

Replace this:

```
socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId)
```

With this:

```
io.to(roomId).emit('user-connected', userId);
```

For further information, please refer this documentation: [Socket.io rooms](https://socket.io/docs/v4/rooms/)